# setup.py contains License in classifiers, but the installed wheel has license=UNKNOWN

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I make a wheel out of my local package with
*python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel*
The file setup.py contains License in the classifiers, as proposed in the docs:

```
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
    ]
```

The file LICENSE is present and found when the wheel was being prepared. 
Still, upon installing this wheel, I get License=UNKNOWN.
What should I do to include it?
I use python 3.7, the packages are all up-to-date.

I'm sorry, I'm new to this packaging routine, so maybe the question is silly, but no googling helped me whatsoever here.

UPD: seems like I cannot import it, either! 
Here's the log of setup.py if it matters

```
running sdist
running egg_info
writing db_utils.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to db_utils.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to db_utils.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'db_utils.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating db_utils-1.0.0
creating db_utils-1.0.0\db_utils.egg-info
copying files to db_utils-1.0.0...
copying README.md -> db_utils-1.0.0
copying __init__.py -> db_utils-1.0.0
copying fetcher.py -> db_utils-1.0.0
copying setup.py -> db_utils-1.0.0
copying db_utils.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> db_utils-1.0.0\db_utils.egg-info
copying db_utils.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> db_utils-1.0.0\db_utils.egg-info
copying db_utils.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> db_utils-1.0.0\db_utils.egg-info
copying db_utils.egg-info\top_level.txt -> db_utils-1.0.0\db_utils.egg-info
Writing db_utils-1.0.0\setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'db_utils-1.0.0' (and everything under it)
running bdist_wheel
running build
installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
running install
running install_egg_info
Copying db_utils.egg-info to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\db_utils-1.0.0-py3.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
adding license file "LICENSE" (matched pattern "LICEN[CS]E*")
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\db_utils-1.0.0.dist-info\WHEEL
creating 'dist\db_utils-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel' to it
adding 'db_utils-1.0.0.dist-info/LICENSE'
adding 'db_utils-1.0.0.dist-info/METADATA'
adding 'db_utils-1.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL'
adding 'db_utils-1.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt'
adding 'db_utils-1.0.0.dist-info/RECORD'
removing build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
```

It is installed into c:\users\XXXXX\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages
which I added to my PYTHONPATH. 
I'm really lost, please help.

Comment: From the log output; looks like the `LICENSE` file is addedto the _wheel_. You might want to check that the [`license` parameter is filled](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#license). Show the `setup.py` and/or `setup.cfg`.

Comment: There's an extract of setup.py with classifiers above.

Comment: The classifiers are not made for this. Read the guide I linked: "this information is only used for searching & browsing projects on PyPI". You need to provide a value to the `license` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, thank you, this works. Somehow this parameter isn't mentioned in the official docs (though, the entry in the classifiers is). Still, I cannot import it, but I'll take my time to try to solve it by myself. Thank you!

Comment: OK, no idea what doc you are following right now. Anyway, not sure, but it looks like you have a `__init__.py` file right next to `setup.py`, which is usually not what you should do. The `__init__.py` file should be placed in a directory to make it a package, something like `my_top_level_package/__init__.py`, and then you can do `import my_top_level_package`. It'd be easier if you showed `setup.py` as well as the directory structure.

Comment: [Distutils docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data) lists the `license` parameter.

Comment: You're right, that's what I had, __init__.py and setup.py + modules together, that's my error, apparently. 
As far as the documentation is concerned, I meant https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/  -- thank you for the suggestion of distutils docs, that's a meaningful read. I'll try to check if restructuring my project this way will help, thanks!

Comment: Yep, everything's working fine, many thanks!